# Быстрая загрузка в базу MYSQL с минимальным количеством запросов

Tags: php, долгий-запрос, mysql

Есть база данных, в которую записывается товар.

Вопрос: можно уменьшить количество запросов в цикле до 1-го, т.е. как сделать так, чтобы данные товара записывались и потом отправлялись одним запросом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Цикл можно убрать, сделать один insert

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

Более подробно [тут](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html)

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант -  использование транзакций [читать тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.transactions.php)